# Only append div with certain class in Ajax success function

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have a partial view that is used to return a bunch of html to my main page. In my Ajax call, I need to grab that partial view, but I only want to append certain `<div>` elements. Is this possible?

Here is the Ajax:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#addItem").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("BlankDropDownItem", "DropDownValues")',
                data: { field: $('#Field').val(), displayPage: $('#DisplayPage').val() },
                dataType: 'html',
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) {
                    $("#items").append(html);
                }
            });                
            return false;
        });
    });
```

This calls an ASP MVC controller method which returns this partial view.

```
    <div id="LeftDiv" style="width:250px;float:left;">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Category Information</legend>
            <div class="M-editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Field)
            </div>
            <div class="M-editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Field)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Field)
            </div>
            <div class="M-editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DisplayPage)
            </div>
            <div class="M-editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DisplayPage)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DisplayPage)
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div id="RightDiv" style="width:300px;float:left; padding-left:50px;">
        <fieldset id="items">
            <legend>Drop Down Items</legend>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AllowedValue)
            </div>
            <div class="label-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AllowedValue)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AllowedValue)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DisplayValue)
            </div>
            <div class="label-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DisplayValue)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DisplayValue)
            </div>
        </fieldset>
     </div>
```

However, I only want to append the `label-field` and `editor-label` `<div>` elements to `items`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to search the returned html too.  Not as efficient as it could be, but probably fine for your purposes.

```
$("#items").append($(html).find(".label-field, .editor-label"));
```